# how to get post value in AM/PM in php?

Tags: php

I want to show the post data in AM or PM but unable to get the result. Kindly check what I am doing:

```
<input id="monday" type="time" name="monday" value="13:30">
//Here I submit 04:15 PM


<?php
$monday = $_POST['monday'];  // Storing Selected Value In Variable
var_dump('You have selected :'.$monday);
$newDateTime = date('h:i A', strtotime($monday));

console.log($monday);       // Output : 04:15
console.log($newDateTime);  // Output : 16:15

?>
```

I want the desired output:
    04:15PM

Comment: If you're able to `console.log` in php, I'd be quite impressed

Comment: if you posted the string `13:30` you can do `date( 'g:i A', strtotime('13:30') );`

Comment: I can't recreate the problem, just tried it in interactive console:            
php > echo date('h:i A', strtotime('16:15'));
04:15 PM

Comment: I find it odd that @HamzaNig edited the question to be different than what the OP submitted. Even if print is correct, the OP had console.log(), odd.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `console.log` is a JavaScript function, not a PHP one.

You can either use `print` or `echo` to output content, like this:

```
$monday = new \DateTime();

echo date_format($monday, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
#output: 2018-10-218 17:45:12

echo date_format($monday, 'G:ia');
#output: 05:45pm
```